# audio waveform video with background image

Tags: video, ffmpeg, waveform

I wish to generate a video waveform from a .wav file and a picture .jpg. I can generate a waveform video using

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mkv
```

but how can I add a background picture?

Thank you.

Comment: Next time posting, please include the full, uncut command line output, not just the command that you tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add your image as another input, and then you can use something like the `colorkey` filter to make the `showwaves` visualization's background transparent and the `overlay` filter to blend the `showwaves` visualization and your background image.

Try something like:

```
ffmpeg -i $audio -i $picture -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line,colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.1,format=yuva420p[v];[1:v]scale=1280:720[bg];[bg][v]overlay[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mkv
```

Breaking down the differences from your starting point:

- `colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.1` is going to take any black in the video generated by `showwaves` and make it transparent.
- `format=yuva420p` is needed to convert both video streams to the same pixel format.
- `[1:v]scale=1280:720[bg]` takes the video from input #1, scales it to match our `showwaves` size, and names the output `[bg]` (background). You can change this to e.g. `scale=1280:-1` to scale one dimension to 1280 and scale the other proportionally keeping the aspect ratio.
- `[bg][v]overlay[outv]` is taking the still-image video `[bg]` as well as the video stream we just generated from `showwaves` and named `[v]` and overlaying them so that the image in `[1:v]` shows through the transparent parts we've keyed out in `[v]`. The output is named `[outv]`.
- One of the `-map` arguments has now been changed to use `[outv]` (the output from the overlay filter) instead of `[v]` (just the colorkeyed `showwaves` output) as the video source in your output.

Comment: Thank you.I did ffmpeg -i 5DD62F56.wav -i b.jpg -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line,colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.1,format=yuv420p[v];[1:v][v]overlay[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy outputh.mkv but the result is this image (screenshot) with no waveform though there is audio : https://i.imgur.com/hue1daT.jpg

Comment: I found this command on the net : ffmpeg -y -i 5DD62F56.mp3 -loop 1 -i b.jpg -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line,colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.1,format=yuva420p[v];[1:v][v]overlay[outv]" -map "[outv]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest output1.mp4 and it is working fine...(to be followed)

Comment: ... Except that the waveform appears only on a part of the image (on the left first 1/3 rd). I guess there is a correlation to find between the waveform and the image size, but what? how? so that the waveform runs from the left part of the image to the right part. Also, for I don't know which reason, I have to input a mp3 as a wav didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I finally found out. Here is the right command for me : ffmpeg -y -i 5DD62F56.mp3 -loop 1 -i b.jpg -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line,colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.1,format=yuva420p[v];[1:v][v]overlay[outv]" -map "[outv]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest output1.mp4 My problem was that the image size should be the same as the one indicated in showwaves=s=1280x720 . Thank you for your help! :-)

Comment: Yes, you can add another filter to resize your input image to 1280x720 if you want. I'll add that to the answer -- consider marking it as accepted?